# Python program that finds perfect cube

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written this code but when I write 64, it says not perfect cube, why?

```
num=int(input('num: '))


for i in range(0,num+1):

    if num==i**3:
        print('It is perfect cube')
    else:
        print('not perfect cube')
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to print "not perfect cube" if `num == i**3` is false for *every* value of `i` you check, not just one of them.  Basically, you want your `else` attached to the `for` loop, not the `if` statement,

```
for i in range(num+1):
    if num == i**3:
        print('It is a perfect cube')
        break  # Don't need to check more
else:
    # Only executed if the loop ends "naturally", not via a break
    print('It is not a perfect cube')
```

This gets a little more complicated if you want to stop the loop once `i ** 3 > num`; you need a flag to indicate whether you are breaking because you found the cube root, or because you know there isn't one. One possible approach:

```
cube = False
for i in range(num+1):
    tmp = i ** 3
    if num == tmp:
        print('It is a perfect cube')
        cube = True
        break
    elif num < tmp:
        break
else:
    if not cube:
        print('Not a cube')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import math class
import math
num = int(input('num: '))

# Check cube of number i upto square root of num
# If cube found print the message 'Perfect cube' and exit loop
for i in range(int(math.sqrt(num))+1):
    if i**3 == num:
        print('It is perfect cube')
        break

# Check whether cube was found or not , if not found print the message 'Not perfect cube' 
if i**3 != num:
    print('Not perfect cube')
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast version that will stop evaluating the values after it has found a solution.

```
num = int(input('num: '))
if any(num == i ** 3 for i in range(num)):
    print('perfect cube')
else:
    print('not perfect cube')
```